# Delete All Except One Python

Tags: shell

I have folder with full off different file extensions like : xyz.bue , aks.eu , ejz.ff etc. I would like to have a script or a line of code that deletes all from the file but leaves the ones with ending .ff

Tried to do somehings but always ends with error.

```
ls | grep -v -f ~/.ff | xargs rm
```

I use the code up when i am in the directory where I want to keep .ff files but gives error..

Comment: Python? This seems like UNIX shell (damn this autocorrection feature) for me.

Comment: This is on UNIX shell a line of code I try to use for it to work but I can use a python script to do the same job that was what I mean by it. Does not really metter on the terminal or an a script. I just need it to be done one way or another

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
ls -1 | grep -v -e '.*.ff' | xargs rm
```

- listing all files
- excluding (-v) all files that match the regexp (-e switch): `*.ff`
- then remove them.

*Please test it first, because I did not.*